# Sendmail in Nexenta core 3.0.1

Tags: smtp, sendmail, opensolaris, nexenta

I'm trying to setup sendmail in Nexenta core 3.0.1 (Solaris based OS). All I want is to be able to send emails from that host - like notifications about failures, cron jobs output etc. Initially Nexenta core doesn't have sendmail so here is what I've done:

```
apt-get install sunwsndmu
```

Now there is a sendmail in /usr/sbin/sendmail. When I try to send email from command line:

```
$mail maxim
test
.
```

It doesn't give me any error but in log file I see:

```
Dec 20 12:41:08 nas sendmail[12295]: [ID 801593 mail.info] oBKHf8u7012295: from=maxim, size=107, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201012201741.oBKHf8u7012295@nas>, relay=maxim@localhost
Dec 20 12:41:08 nas sendmail[12295]: [ID 801593 mail.info] oBKHf8u7012295: to=maxim, ctladdr=maxim (1000/10), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30107, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

So I guess I need to have SMTP service running. How do I do that in Nexenta?

```
svcs -a | grep sendmail
```

doesn't return anything and

```
# svcadm enable sendmail
svcadm: Pattern 'sendmail' doesn't match any instances
```

I'm not married to sendmail so if there are easier ways to achieve y goal I'm open to suggestions as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
#svcadm enable smtp
```